Determinant form of Curl of a vector field on a differentiable manifold
I was trying to compute the curl of a vector field on a differentiable manifold in terms of a determinant like in calc 3.
I want to show $\nabla \times v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{det(g)}}\det\begin{pmatrix}\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\ g_{1j}v^j&g_{2j}v^j&g_{3j}v^j\end{pmatrix}$
I was able to compute $\nabla \times v$ on a manifold with a diagonal metric
Suppose $M$ is a 3-manifold with a metric $g=a^2dx^2+b^2dy^2+c^2dz^2$.
Let $v= v^1\partial_1+v^2\partial_2+v^3\partial_3\in TM$ and $v^\flat= v_1dx^1+v_2dx^2+v_3dx^3$.
Then $\nabla \times v=\frac{1}{abc}\det\begin{pmatrix}\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\ a^2v^1& b^2v^2&c^2v^3\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{abc}\det\begin{pmatrix}\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\ v_1& v_2&v_3\end{pmatrix}$
Note that we can compute an orthonormal frame and coframe:
$\frac{1}{a}\partial_1= e_1, 
\frac{1}{b}\partial_2= e_2,
\frac{1}{c}\partial_3= e_3$
$e^1=adx^1, e^2=bdx^2, e^3=cdx^3$
We can compute $\nabla \times v= (*d(v^\flat))^\sharp$
$v^\flat=a^2v^1dx^1+b^2v^2dx^2+c^2v^3dx^3=v_1dx^1+v_2dx^2+v_3dx^3$
$dv^\flat=\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^2}dx^2\wedge dx^1+\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^3}dx^3\wedge dx^1+\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^1}dx^1\wedge dx^2+\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^3}dx^3\wedge dx^2+\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^1}dx^1\wedge dx^3+\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^2}dx^2\wedge dx^3$
$=(\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^2})dx^1\wedge dx^2+(\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^1})dx^3\wedge dx^1+(\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^3})dx^2\wedge dx^3$
$=\frac{1}{ab}(\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^2})e^1\wedge e^2+\frac{1}{ac}(\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^1})e^3\wedge e^1+\frac{1}{bc}(\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^3})e^2\wedge e^3$
So
$*dv^\flat=\frac{1}{bc}(\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^3})e^1+\frac{1}{ac}(\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^1})e^2+\frac{1}{ab}(\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^2})e^3$
Then
$(*dv^\flat)^\sharp=\frac{1}{bc}(\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^3})e_1+\frac{1}{ac}(\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^1})e_2+\frac{1}{ab}(\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^2})e_3$
$=\frac{1}{abc}(\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^3})\partial_1+\frac{1}{abc}(\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x^1})\partial_2+\frac{1}{abc}(\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x^2})\partial_3$
$=\frac{1}{abc}(\frac{\partial (c^2v^3)}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial (b^2v^2)}{\partial x^3})\partial_1+\frac{1}{abc}(\frac{\partial (a^2v^1)}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial (c^2v^3)}{\partial x^1})\partial_2+\frac{1}{abc}(\frac{\partial (b^2v^2)}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial (a^2v^1)}{\partial x^2})\partial_3$
=$\frac{1}{abc}[(\frac{\partial (c^2v^3)}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial (b^2v^2)}{\partial x^3})\partial_1+(\frac{\partial (a^2v^1)}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial (c^2v^3)}{\partial x^1})\partial_2+(\frac{\partial (b^2v^2)}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial (a^2v^1)}{\partial x^2})\partial_3]$
$=\frac{1}{abc}\det\begin{pmatrix}\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\ a^2v^1& b^2v^2&c^2v^3\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{abc}\det\begin{pmatrix}\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\ v_1& v_2&v_3\end{pmatrix}$
In the general case, I believe this becomes
$\nabla \times v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{det(g)}}\det\begin{pmatrix}\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\ g_{1j}v^j&g_{2j}v^j&g_{3j}v^j\end{pmatrix}$
The difference between my calculation and the more general one is the raising and lowering operations and the hodge star.
